# Smart way to add and remove URL rewrite rules in C# at runtime?

Tags: c#, configuration, url-rewriting

Some static URL rewrite section from my web.config:

```
<rewrite>
   <rules>
      <rule name="Cities" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="Cities/?$" ignoreCase="true" />
        <action type="Rewrite" url="/Cities.aspx" appendQueryString="true" />
      </rule>
   </rules>
</rewrite>
```

I works fine, but I would like to add dynamic rewrite rules at runtime.
Is there a smart way to add and remove URL rewrite rules in C# at runtime?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1178461/progmatically-rewritemap-rules-at-runtime)

Comment: well I agree today but that answer was given back in 2011 when I was still pretty new in SO, anyway the opener has marked it as solution so it helped him :) I would not give an answer like this today ;-)